# Linking different schemas from different mysql servers into only one mysql server so he can manage the queries

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I have 5 different schemas, eventually I want to separate them into different servers for specific RAM and CPU assignment depending on the load.

How can I configure so I can show a schema from a different server into a "front" mysql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-proxy.html):

   > The MySQL Proxy is an application that communicates over the network using the MySQL network protocol and provides communication between one or more MySQL servers and one or more MySQL clients.

   However, note:

   > #### Warning
   >
   > MySQL Proxy is currently an Alpha release and should not be used within production environments.
2. [The `FEDERATED` Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/federated-storage-engine.html):

   > The `FEDERATED` storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local `FEDERATED` table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.
3. [Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html):

   > Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master) to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).

   However, note:

   > In this environment, all writes and updates must take place on the master server. Reads, however, may take place on one or more slaves.